# mongoDB updateOne not updating a record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I am trying to update a record in mongoDB using updateOne, the un updating record is in array, and all fields are updating except one field which is **country**, I have tried to update it using MongoChef (a GUI of MongoDB for linux), but it doesn't work, also **If I update one the Document using Edit in GUI then that record is ready to update after that**.

I have tried with the following query in MongoChef

```
db.institutions.updateOne({
    "campus": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": ObjectId("578500ef87e4c326183e520e")} },
    "_id": ObjectId("57f25706762c06cb7d9422fc") 
    },
    {
    "$set" : { "campus.$.country" : "SS1"
    }
});
```

Only country field is not updating If I update any other field it works fine.

The document structure is listed under

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f26824762c06cb7d982e37"), 
    "campus" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("578500ee87e4c326183e5201"), 
            "country" : "GB", 
            "coreId" : NumberInt(1), 
            "city" : "Norwich", 
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance any help is appreciatiable

Comment: Can you show us the document you get when you query `db.institutions.findOne({ "_id": ObjectId("57f25706762c06cb7d9422fc") })`?

Comment: @chridam
My find query is
db.institutions.find({
"campus.country" : "SS1",
"_id" : ObjectId("57f26824762c06cb7d982e37")
},
{
"campus": true
});


{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f26824762c06cb7d982e37"), 
    "campus" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("578500ee87e4c326183e5201"), 
            "country" : "GB", 
            "coreId" : NumberInt(14677), 
            "city" : "Norwich"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: But that's totally different from the query in your update where you are querying for a document with `{ "_id": ObjectId("57f25706762c06cb7d9422fc")  }`

Comment: It changed when Db is imported again, there is no problem of id dear

Answer (score 3):

try this query

```
db.institutions.updateOne(
    {
      "campus._id": ObjectId("578500ef87e4c326183e520e"),
      "_id": ObjectId("57f25706762c06cb7d9422fc") 
    },
    {
      "$set" : { "campus.$.country" : "SS1"}
    }
);
```

**N.B:** if use mongodb driver or mongoose then no need to use `ObjectId("")` just use `"578500ef87e4c326183e520e"`

Comment: where are you run this query means mongo shell or anything ?

Comment: I am running this query from project and also in MongoChef (a GUI for mongodb)

Comment: for your project use like `"_id": "57f25706762c06cb7d9422fc"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124868/discussion-between-shahbaz-and-shaishab-roy).