# pymongo UpdateOne does not update a field but do another

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844882/mongodb-updateone-not-updating-a-record) has my problem too but no one answer that. I have a model in the mongodb with some fields in which one of them named `synced` which is a boolean field.
With the code below I want to update one (or with some minor changes more than one) document's "synced" field:

```
db.bulk_write([UpdateOne({'content_id': '6101-1514301051'}, {'$set': {'synced': True}})]).bulk_api_result
```

But the result says that one matched doc found with no update:

```
{'writeErrors': [],
 'writeConcernErrors': [],
 'nInserted': 0,
 'nUpserted': 0,
 'nMatched': 1,
 'nModified': 0,
 'nRemoved': 0,
 'upserted': []}
```

And when I do the same only with another field I get the right answer and the update successfully applied:

```
db.bulk_write([UpdateOne({'content_id': '6101-1514301051'}, {'$set': {'visit': 14201}})]).bulk_api_result 
{'writeErrors': [],
 'writeConcernErrors': [],
 'nInserted': 0,
 'nUpserted': 0,
 'nMatched': 1,
 'nModified': 1,
 'nRemoved': 0,
 'upserted': []}
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I apply the changes to the `synced` filed?

**MORE INFO:**

I also do the same thing with mongo-shell:

```
> db.my_model_name.updateOne({"content_id": "6101-1514301051"}, {$set: {"synced": true}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

or with

```
> db.telegram_post_model.update({"content_id": "6101-1514301051"}, {$set: {"synced": true}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

But still cannot update the document.

Comment: Can you provide an example of documents that are in that database?

Comment: In first example the content_id matched your query ('nMatched': 1) but 'synced' already had the value True , so actually no data changed ('nModified': 0). But in second example 'visit'  value got updated so 'nModified': 1

Answer (score -1):

Following code works good for me:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient("mongodb://login:password@server:port/database_name").get_default_database()
db.telegram_post_model.update({"content_id": "6101-1514301051"}, {"$set": {"synced": True}})
```

Comment: I do this also in the mongo shell but this was not the answer

Comment: Ok,  another option document is not modified because it already contains that value or something like that. From code/query view everything is correct. Maybe you have some code running on the same database, maybe something else. But I'm not sure if anybody can guess that.

Comment: BTW, @EmadHelmi can you reproduce this issue in other environments, on copy of database on another instance?